# Compiling custom FFMPEG for mp3/wav to flac conversion

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, compilation, centos

I need to compile ffmpeg from source for CentOS. The goal it to convert MP3 and WAV to FLAC. I tried to compile ffmpeg with this guide: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos 
and it worked fine, but took approximately 20min and compiled a bunch unnecessary things, even thought I did not used next options as recommended in guide, but used:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
--prefix="/opt/tmg/ffmpeg_build" \
--pkg-config-flags="--static" \
--extra-cflags="-I/opt/tmg/ffmpeg_build/include" \
--extra-ldflags="-L/opt/tmg/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
--extra-libs=-lpthread \
--extra-libs=-lm \
--bindir="/opt/tmg/ffmpeg_build/bin" \
--enable-gpl \
--enable-libfreetype
```

My question is what do I need for MP3 and WAV to FLAC and how do I compile just that part?

I found in configuration `--disable-all` option, but what do I have to enable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
./configure --disable-everything --disable-network --disable-autodetect --enable-decoder=mp3*,pcm* --enable-encoder=flac --enable-parser=mpegaudio --enable-demuxer=mp3,wav --enable-muxer=flac --enable-filter=aresample --enable-protocol=file
```

- You didn't mention needing to support cover/album art, so this assumes you don't need it. Make sure your encoding command uses `-map 0:a` or `-vn` or similar to ignore embedded images. Otherwise, you'll have to enable a bunch of stuff to handle the images.
- You may get warnings during configure such as `WARNING: Disabled mp3_at_decoder because not all dependencies are satisfied: audiotoolbox`. These can be ignored.
- Use `--disable-everything` instead of `--disable-all` because the second option disables too much and is harder to use (unless you know what you are doing and are willing to perform many test compiles) due to the complexity of component inter-dependencies.

Comment: Okay. So if I want to add mp3 to mp3 split functionality like this: `ffmpeg -i somefile.mp3 -f segment -segment_time 3 -c copy out%03d.mp3` I have to change configuration like this: `./configure --disable-everything --disable-network --disable-autodetect --enable-decoder=mp3*,pcm* --enable-encoder=flac --enable-libmp3lame--enable-parser=mpegaudio --enable-demuxer=mp3,wav --enable-muxer=flac,mp3 --enable-filter=aresample --enable-protocol=file`

Comment: @Arttu Almost. You need to enable the segment muxer too. No need for `--enable-libmp3lame` because you're stream copying and not encoding. `./configure --disable-everything --disable-network --disable-autodetect --enable-decoder=mp3*,pcm* --enable-encoder=flac --enable-parser=mpegaudio --enable-demuxer=mp3,wav --enable-muxer=flac,segment,mp3 --enable-filter=aresample --enable-protocol=file`