# How to build ffmpeg to get the smallest static library? I only want convert 3gp to mp4

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, 3gp

I need to convert 3gp files into MP4 format files in my iOS App. I use ffmpeg to convert. But the complete ffmpeg package increased my app by 6MB. How do I build ffmpeg to get the smallest static library? I only need this function: convert 3gp video into MP4 format.

Comment: Related answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54756991/ https://stackoverflow.com/a/59040157/ https://stackoverflow.com/a/27912864/ https://stackoverflow.com/q/64943357/